# dynamically inserting html specific to a clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve a very similar feel to this http://www.hausofmagdalen.com/.

Using jQuery .toggle I can hide or show a div(text box) above the gallery specific to a selected gallery image. However, when clicking multiple images successively I get all the text boxes showing . To put it another way, the text boxes don't cancel each other out.

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post some of your code? maybe http://www.jsfiddle.net link?

Comment: Something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vqtfgxto/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vqtfgxto/) ?

Comment: Spot on LShetty.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, I have put together an example based on my own assumptions. See if that's what you wanted.

```js
$(".items").on("click", "li", function() {
    $("#box").html($(this).html());
}).find("li").first().click();
```

```css
#box { width: 250px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid; }
ul { overflow: hidden; margin: 10px; padding: 0; }
li { width: 80px; border: 1px solid green; overflow: hidden; float: left; margin: 0 10px; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<ul class="items">
    <li>As you can see, the reason behind is the willing to give as much as information I can whenever you inspect an element</li>
    <li>classes the porpouse is to have a placeholder with no style at all that we can bind with our javascript code without mixing</li>
    <li>In the first declaration you obviously understand that we are talking about a button but you might not be sure which one</li>
    <li>You have to trust me even if at first it might seems to be a bit silly but when your site grows up as much as your blocks </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#gallery').html($('.selected-video').html());
```